# Do I need a visa to travel to Paris from London?

Tags: visas, france, uk-citizens, visa-free-entry, freedom-of-movement

I am a British citizen and I am going to Paris via the Eurostar from London. I am going to be in Paris for 3 nights.

Do I need a visa?

Comment: Although it is very unlikely, it's always possible the situation could change and visas would be required. Visas were required (due to terrorist activity) of some otherwise generally worthy foreigners back in the [mid-1980s](http://www.nytimes.com/1986/09/15/world/france-to-require-visas-for-visitors-to-combat-terror.html). Switzerland and EC member countries were excluded from the requirement, but Americans and Canadians were included. The visa was the type that looked like a postage stamp rather than the rubber stamp or sticker type.

Comment: Remember to re-poke that question if/when the UK decides to trigger article 50.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a EU citizen, you are entitled to visa free entry throughout the EU. You need proof that you are an EU citizen, and the easiest way to provide this is with your passport.

Furthermore, as a UK citizen, you enjoy [visa free access to 83 countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_British_citizens) - not including those in the EU. It is safe to say, you enjoy a great deal of freedom of movement even outside the EU.

Answer (score 4):

No you don't need a visa.

> Do you need a visa? : If you are a British citizen or from another EU
>   country, you only need a valid passport or ID for the whole length of
>   your stay in France. <sup>[source](http://www.ambafrance-uk.org/Tourism-in-France-25720)</sup>